# Why can't I create a symbolic link in /usr/bin?

Tags: symlink, administration

I'm trying to create a sym link in my /usr/bin directory as the command drush8

But every time I do it, it doesn't show up in /usr/bin but instead says it already exists. It's thinking that it exists in the drush8/drush directory, but I want it in /usr/bin

My file is located in /usr/bin/drush8/vendor/drush/drush/drush

And I want it as a symlink in /usr/bin as **drush8**

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You already have a directory called `drush8` in `/usr/bin`, you can't also have a link (or any other kind of file) with the same name.

If you want `drush8` to work as a command, you could add the appropriate folder to your `$PATH` or define an alias.

Generally speaking folders such as `drush8` would go in `/opt`, that way you'd avoid this problem... Strictly speaking your symlink should go in `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/usr/bin`.

Comment: i see. thanks. so /opt stands for what? so in linux /opt would be the equivalent of program_files in windows? and /usr/bin would have all the executable files?

Comment: `/opt` is intended for third-party software that installa in its own directory; the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) has more details. It is similar to `Program Files` in Windows... `/usr/bin` is normally reserved for executables provided by your distribution's packages.

Comment: @StephenKitt - sorry to jump onto an old post... but very helpful. I looked around to see where other things were installed and decided to install at `/usr/share/` is that similar to `/opt` or different? - Maybe this should a separate question...

Comment: @tom no, it’s quite different (see the FHS link above). As a general rule, on Linux distributions, you should leave everything apart from `/usr/local`, `/opt`, `/home` and `/srv` alone (outside those four directories, everything is managed by your distribution).

Comment: @StephenKitt - many thanks for pointing out the FHS link - that is so useful - I did not see it before - program moved to /opt with symlink or similar in /usr/local/bin. Thanks so much for your help with this - should I ask a question for your to answer with this link?